# DCMTK_ENABLE_CHARSET_CONVERSION can not be enabled

Tags: c++, dcmtk

i'm trying to build dcmtk-3.6.6 using Cmake Gui https://github.com/DCMTK/dcmtk to convert a dcm file to Json, i faced the same problem in this link https://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=4769  i can't enable the option **DCMTK_ENABLE_CHARSET_CONVERSION** in my cmake Gui (as you can see in the image, only disabled is show ) , i tried to build it with both **DCMTK_WITH_CONV** and **DCMTK_WITH_ICU** to be able to use convertToUTF8() but it seems that does not work [image]

we can see in the second image that DCMTK_ENABLE_CHARSET_CONVERSION Is not defined

[image]
Could someone help me ? thanks

EDIT : my cmakeGui log show that he didn't find ICU, so probably the problem are coming from me, how can i install ICU ?
[image]

Comment: I think you need to build with iconv or ICU for this to be enabled. You wrote that you tried that, but it didn't work - what exactly did not work?

Comment: i replied my Post, i my cmake GUI log show that they didn't find ICU library

Comment: As far as I remember, you have to download the sources for iconv or ICU and point cmake to them. Can't check it now, as I'm not at a PC.

Comment: If you are using VisualStudio on Windows, the easiest way is probably to download the official support libraries from here: https://dcmtk.org/dcmtk#lib-win

Comment: Of course, reading DCMTK's INSTALL file would also be useful: https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/file_install.html